# Как получить Uri записи SQLite Android

Tags: java, android, sql, android-studio, sqlite

у меня имеется база данных SQLite в которую я добавляю и удаляю данные по принципу описанному ниже

```
public long add(String name, long remindDate, String icon, String background, String imagesPath) {
    try {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();        
        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
        long createDate = date.getTimeInMillis();
        contentValues.put(ConstantsDB.KEY_NAME, name); //текст заметки
        contentValues.put(ConstantsDB.KEY_CREATE_DATE, createDate); // дата создания
        contentValues.put(ConstantsDB.KEY_REMIND_DATE, remindDate); // время и дата напоминания
        contentValues.put(ConstantsDB.KEY_ICON, icon); // иконка
        contentValues.put(ConstantsDB.KEY_BACKGROUND, background); //заливка
        contentValues.put(ConstantsDB.KEY_NOTE_IMAGES_PATH, imagesPath); // путь к файлу
        long rowID = database.insert(ConstantsDB.DB_TABLE_NAME, ConstantsDB.KEY_ID, contentValues);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--------Адаптер Апдейт---------Test ROW ID  = " + rowID);
        return rowID;
```

Так же при создании новой записи я получаю ее ID в БД, как мне получить Uri этой записи в бд такого формата?

> content://com.example.aplication/pathdb/3

Буду признателен за любые ответы

Comment: непонятно, что вы хотите? Вы хотите по URI делать запрос к базе и получать объект?

Comment: мне нужен URI строки БД которую я только что добавил, чтобы дальше уже я мог работать с этим Uri при создании уведомлений

Comment: `Uri` не имеет никакого отношения к `SQLite`. Если вы хотите шарить данные из базы по `Uri`, то вы должны реализовать `ContentProvider`, в котором сами составлять `Uri` и предоставлять данные по нему. Если оно вам надо посмотрите этот урок: [Урок 101. Создаем свой ContentProvider](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/166-urok-101-sozdaem-svoj-contentprovider.html)